# How to use enum value in Text in compose Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, android-jetpack-compose

I have a enum

```
enum class variantUnitOptions {
    KG,
    BUNDLE,
    BOX,
    PIECE
}
```

And I have a sealed class like this

```
sealed class VariantUnit {
    class ListOfUnits(val value: List<String>) : VariantUnit()
    class SelectedUnit(val value: variantUnitOptions) : VariantUnit()
}
```

Now I have another data class which uses VariantUnit

```
data class VariantModal(
     val variantId: String,
     val variantName: String,
     val variantUnit: VariantUnit,
     val productId: String,
     val variantQuantity: Int,
)
```

I am creating an instance of this data class

```
val variant = VariantModal("id","name",VariantUnit.SelectedUnit(variantUnitOptions.BUNDLE),"pid",5)
```

Now I am using Text to display the VariantUnit:

```
Text(){
      text = variant.variantQuantity.toString(),    
}
```

I have used toString() to convert the enum value to a string and am expecting the text to be BUNDLE but I am getting ihp.project.ihpagents.data.VariantUnit$SelectedUnit@456cb0b as text.

How to get the value of the enum ? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectedUnit` does not override the default `toString` function, so the result is `ihp.project.ihpagents.data.VariantUnit$SelectedUnit@456cb0b`. You need to override the toString function of SelectedUnit class

```
class SelectedUnit(val value: variantUnitOptions) : VariantUnit() {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return value.toString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
Text(){
      text = (variant.variantUnit as? VariantUnit.SelectedUnit)?.value?.name.orEmpty(),    
}
```

First, you need to check what VariantUnit is, and then retrieve the "value" and "name."